# Connect js library Joomla 3

Tags: javascript, joomla

I change

```
JHTML::script("dhtmlxgrid/dhtmlxcommon.js",'media/com_telecomax/js/');
```

to

`JHTML::script("com_telecomax/dhtmlxgrid/dhtmlxcommon.js");`  in **\administrator\components\mycomponent\views\info\tmpl\default.php**

but it don't connect script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following method:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . "components/com_telecomax/dhtmlxgrid/dhtmlxcommon.js");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If this answered your questions correctly then please mark the answer as correct